# Can i use android processor like folding@Home to boost an old laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu, android

Android devices are so powerful today you can virtually use it as a stand-alone desktop. I have an old Acer 5515 laptop with a single core AMD processor and I also have a quad-code android and i want to use its processor power(android) to boost my laptop performance. I searched google and there's no one yet out there at this point. So can anyone here suggest anything? I can code in c# and android and i thought of transferring  data using USB interface/API.

Comment: Related (and probably easier, if you'd ask me): [Can I connect an Android phone to an external monitor, keyboard and mouse?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/can-i-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-external-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse) and http://www.ubuntu.com/phone / http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_for_Android.

Comment: i can do that but i have to buy another hdmi monitor and a usb hub that can charge the android while being used.

Answer (score 4):

This is effectively impossible for several reasons.

First and foremost is the fact that your mobile phone processor and laptop processor have almost nothing in common. They are completely different architectures and are not code compatible. Any code you want to run on one **will not** be able to run the other without **a lot** of work.

The assumption that your mobile processor is as powerful as a desktop is also a fallacy.  Mobile phone processors are built for low-power and generally have <5 watt processors, laptops have >35 watt processors and desktops anywhere up to 100 watt. Those numbers are not just implying that desktops are massively inefficient, there is an order of magnitude difference in complexity between mobile and desktop processors.

You can try and appeal to me that they both run Java, but Java is an interpreted language and requires a JIT compiler on the machine that is to run the code. That compiler has to be tailored to the architecture it is running on and features supported on one will not necessarily be supported by the other.

Even if both your phone and laptop processors were architecture compatible this is still not an easy task.  Say you want your phone to do the major grunt-work of playing a video or something.  Video decoding isn't as easy as you think it is.  Your phone has dedicated hardware capable of decoding video, and if you wanted to watch it on your computer you would then have to send the processed data back over the network to your computer.  This means it would have to re-encode it to something your computer *could* handle and as powerful as you think your mobile is, this feat is difficult enough for a number of desktops and well beyond what your mobile can do in real time.

You cannot simply "package" up little bits of work and pipe them elsewhere and then get them back without a major infrastructure in place to support it.  The reason Folding@Home does it is because they can package up a dedicated piece of software to run on every machine, and then package up big chunks of work for each machine to do and send the result back.  For each "package" to be worth splitting out it has to take a reasonably long amount of time to do to offset the cost of packaging in the first place.  There is no realistic way you could package up the small amount of work to, say, display a web-page in any way that would be faster than simply doing on your laptop in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely you can do this. But only if you have Linux environment on both devices. If your mobile processor has more then 4 cores or you can say quad core. Because if it is less than 4 then no meaning of doing all this shit. You need to learn open MPI( open message passing interface) for this. This is a C library developed bay Cisco and Amazon. It is also available in java but I suggest C over java. Because C is lot more faster than java and here we are talking about speed. Open MPI provides distributed processing of a single task. You can also use more then 1 smartphone. Where your one node is master node usually computer or laptop and others will become slave nodes.
Your master node will decide the task, distribute to the slaves and get back calculated results from salves. Even you can use any other computer as a slave. But still it is very very difficult task because you have to develop a program for master and as well as slave for each different task you want to perform.

I am sorry if I made any grammatical mistake. I don't know English much.

Basic info about Open MPI:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_MPI

Running an MPI Cluster within a LAN:
http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/

Exaple:
15418.courses.cs.cmu.edu/spring2013/article/22

Download:
www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v2.1/

Comment: Any references or supporting articles?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's possible if you have a build server:-)

The best way is installing a full linux environment in android. An app named complete linux installer can do this(root).

But most distro doesn't offer cross compiler. Also, ARM devices are to weak to process desktop work.

If you want to boost your compile experience, yes.

But if overall experience, it's almost impossible.

Comment: Sorry if my question confused you. I was asking if i can boost old laptop by borrowing some cpu power from the android device.

Comment: It's almost impossible to do it due to lack of software.

Comment: Example: I want to play 4K video but my old laptop can't handle it so i code a c# program that sends request plus data to the android device which has also a program that accepts the request and crunches data and outputs it as video data sending it back through usb(coz this is the fastest way i think) and the laptop program plays it without hiccups. like this http://phys.org/news/2010-12-air-playstation-3s-supercomputer.html

Comment: You can do it with mirroring like chromecast or some built in feautures. But there is no software to build a cluster on ARM.

Comment: let's make one and profit Ishi

Comment: It's almost impossible for you. First you need to make a linux kernel module and it is C. Also it doesn't make sense because arm devices are really weak... I recommend you to use the phone directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

per software maybe possibly done, it must be specific and done per kernel element so as you finish each even before you may forget what conept you abstract for a particular coding entity, you have already typed/compiled, even documented the source code.
It will be a really bloody task if you'd distribute tasks of whole system so do it per fragment but make an outline first how the system decides or prioritizes what (first) to allocate computing to
Then code per agent device, ugh
It would be a lot easier if it's a utility software distributing CPU computing tasks and the master device acts like a server in that case.